# Is Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response header case-sensitive?

Tags: javascript, html, http-headers, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to access content of site A, from site B. So, I config the Access-Control-Allow-Origin of site B to wildcard (*). However, after the configuration I will got cross-origin exception. Then, I try to curl the site A url, and get this result:

```
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

So, I am not sure is it because the keyword Access-Control-Allow-Origin is case sensitive?

I tried to search around, cannot find any doc specify that it must be camel case.

**Updated:**

Let me explain what really happens to me:

1. I have site B (https://siteB.com) which has a iframe with src="*https://siteA.com*".
2. On site B, I have a script to get dynamic height for that iframe:

   `function showPageDialog(url, id, title, onCloseDialog) {
       var iframe = $('<iframe/>', {'class': 'frame', 'src': url}).load(function(){
           setTimeout(function() {
               $(iframe).height($(iframe).contents().height());
           }, 100);
       });
       showDialog(iframe, id, title, onCloseDialog);
   }`

This function got exception when access *$(iframe).contents()*, the exception detail as follow:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://siteB.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Here is the curl result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
ETag: "f8daec99fedb6b0cd0d205598167cf11:1477550373"
Last-Modified: Thu, 27 Oct 2016 06:39:33 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 44152
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 09:14:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
```

As mentioned in @duskwuff's answer, I alr had `Access-Control-Allow-*` in the response header from siteA. But still get exception.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I miss that post! :p

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 7):

No, the header is not case-sensitive.

Your problem is simpler: the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers only affect the site that the header appears on. A header sent by Site B can only grant access by scripts to Site B; it cannot grant access to a separate Site A.

If you want to access Site A from a script running on Site B, you will need to have Site A add `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers, or find another solution that doesn't involve accessing it from a script.

Comment: ur answer got my point, can u take a look at the updated question, and give me some suggestion on workaround?